# how to make google chart moving and update dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts, google-visualization

I really don't know how to make this google chart moving, honestly and will be asking for help again out there .I really need it badly.. I want to make my google chart moving from the database because my database is collecting data automatically.I want the chart will move with automatic update without refreshing it. the following is my javascript code:

**The output of the following code**
[image: the output of the following code]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- EXTERNAL LIBS-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- EXAMPLE SCRIPT -->
    <script>

    google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawChart,
    packages: ['corechart']
    });

      // onload callback
      function drawChart() {



        // JSONP request
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: 'livedata.php',
          dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function (results) {

          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

          data.addColumn('date', 'time_stamp');
          data.addColumn('number', 'ph');
          data.addColumn('number', 'moist');


          $.each(results, function (i, row) {

          data.addRow([
         new Date(row.time_stamp),
          parseFloat(row.ph),
          parseFloat(row.moist)
            ]);
          });

          var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($('#chart').get(0));

          chart.draw(data, {
          title: 'Soil Analysis',
          curveType: 'function',
          displayAnnotations: true
          //legend: { position: 'bottom' }
          //pointSize: 10
          });

       });

      }
      drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 10000);

      // load chart lib


      // call drawChart once google charts is loaded
    //  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    </script>



  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 80%;height:380px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I dont know if this will also affect my chart for making it move but the following also is my php json code:

```
$query = "SELECT readingID, moist, ph , time_stamp FROM soilReading";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$data_points = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
$wholedate = date('c',strtotime($row['time_stamp']));  
$monthNum = date('m',strtotime($row['time_stamp']));
$DayNum = date('d', strtotime($row['time_stamp']));   
$yearnum = date('Y', strtotime($row['time_stamp']));   
$dateObj   = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
$monthName = $dateObj->format('F');
if(($monthNum == "9")&&($yearnum == "2017")){
      if (array_key_exists($DayNum, $data_points)) {
      $data_points[$DayNum]->ph += $row['ph'] / $data_points[$DayNum]->ph = count($row['ph']);
      $data_points[$DayNum]->moist += $row['moist'];
          }else{
      //$data_points[$DayNum]->ts = $yearnum."".$monthName ."".$DayNum;
     // $data_points[$DayNum]->ts = $yearnum."".$monthNum."".$DayNum;
      $data_points[$DayNum]->time_stamp =$wholedate;
      //$data_points[$DayNum]->ts = $wholedate;      
      $data_points[$DayNum]->ph = $row['ph'] /  $data_points[$DayNum]->ph = count($row['ph']);
      $data_points[$DayNum]->moist = $row['moist'];   

  }
}
  }
$jsonResult = json_encode(array_values($data_points));
echo $jsonResult;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the point in using **jsonData** variable? It looks like it's not required at all. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'livedata.php',
   dataType: 'json',
}).done(function (results) {    
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

also make use of `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);` as you tried. It will ensure that **drawChart** will run after Google Api is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

when you say *move*, are you referring to `animation`?

if so, you'll want to save a reference to the chart

drawing the same chart with new data will allow
the chart to animate from one data set to the next

i've also added a chart option for `animation`

try setup similar to following...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart($('#chart').get(0));

    function drawChart() {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'livedata.php',
        dataType: 'json',
      }).done(function (results) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'time_stamp');
        data.addColumn('number', 'ph');
        data.addColumn('number', 'moist');

        $.each(results, function (i, row) {
          data.addRow([
            new Date(row.time_stamp),
            parseFloat(row.ph),
            parseFloat(row.moist)
          ]);
        });

        chart.draw(data, {
          animation: {
            startup: true,
            duration: 1000
          },
          title: 'Soil Analysis',
          curveType: 'function',
          displayAnnotations: true
        });
      });
    }
    drawChart();
    setInterval(drawChart, 10000);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: thanks again but I'm not referring to animated chart I'm referring to real time moving chart something like this: https://canvasjs.com/editor/?id=https://canvasjs.com/example/gallery/dynamic/realtime_line/ but the data that will move comes from my database in short comes from my json file

Comment: the above, without animation, should work for that effect -- BUT-- the data table will need the same rows of data each draw, only with the first row removed and one row added -- and the redraw will need to occur faster than 10 seconds

Comment: thanks for that.. well I guess be needing some enlightenment for that..

Comment: what does `livedata` return? does any of the data overlap, or is it a fresh new set of rows?